# WCF EndPoint SocketConnction aborted 10 mins after last use

Tags: wcf, sockets, connection, endpoint, abort

the service endpoint socket connection always abort 10 mins after last use.

[image]

the above image shows that the last use of the end point was 10:18:21. after 10 mins, activity Aborted 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' happened. is the 10 mins time out a default setting for WCF endpoint socket connection? can I set the timeout to be infinite? notice the abortion happens on a separate thread(thread 16).

or did I not configure the endpoint correct on the service endpoint?

Comment: How is your WCF service hosted? What binding are you using? Can you post the service's config file?  What is the exception being thrown?  If it's being hosted in IIS, are you closing the proxy after the client is finished using the service?  There's a lot of potential reasons - answering these questions will help narrow it down.

Comment: I am running the WCF EndPoint on a console app using netTcpBinding.

Comment: I am running the WCF EndPoint on a console app using netTcpBinding. this is exception type: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

and exception message: A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data.

Answer (score 0):

The socket connection timeouts needs to be configured on both client and server side (smaller of the two will prevail). These should be done via binding configuration (in config or code). The timeouts can be done via inactivityTimeout setting of a reliableSession, in combination with recieveTimeout of the netTcpBinding. You can also consider using idleTimeouts in the connection pool settings option of netTcpBinding. It is typically not recommended to set infinite timeouts unless you have very specific needs that need to be met and have service usage parameters that safegaurd against infinite timeouts.